# argparse: default for positional argument not working?

Tags: python, argparse

I have:

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser

parser = ArgumentParser(description='Test')
parser.add_argument("command",
                help="the command to be executed",
                choices=["dump", "delete", "update", "set"],
               default="set")
parser.parse_args()
```

But when I run:  `python test.py` I get:

```
usage: test.py [-h] {dump,delete,update,set}
test.py: error: too few arguments
```

Maybe I am just blind sighted today; but I can't figure what should be wrong about my input. Or is this simply not possible with argparse?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For `default` keyword argument to work, you have to add `nargs='*'` like below:

```
parser.add_argument("command",
        help="the command to be executed",
        choices=["dump", "delete", "update", "set"],
        nargs='?',
        default="set"
    )
```

See https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#default for more information :)

Edit by OP: `nargs='*'` allows for multiple commands to be entered. Thus changed to `nargs='?'` as I am looking for **exactly one** command to be entered.

Comment: I think it is better to use `nargs='?'` in OP's case

Comment: @Squizz I know figured: having "*" there ... allows to go for `test.py dump delete` - so I got a list of commands ... but actually I want exactly **one**. Is that possible?

Comment: @GhostCat In that case I'd go for `nargs=1`, or just leave it to be `nargs="*"` then parse the value of parser.parse_args() by doing something like `args=parser.parse_args()` then retrieve the first (or any) argument with `args.command[0]`. It's all up to your design choice!